# How to get gmail of user use my app script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, gmail

I create function get gmail when user use my app in file gs. When i call function via file script html it run but don't get gmail ?

I try test open new web browsers, log in with account gmail and pass URL of apps script but not show my gmail.

Code in file .gs:

```
function checkAccSS(){

 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 Logger.log(email); // I test it show my gmail

 return email;

}
```

Code in file .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
  </head>
  <body  onload="doLoadGmail()">


    <p id="demo"></p>


    <script>   

         function doLoadGmail(){

           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkGmall).checkAccSS();

         }

         function checkGmall(email){         

          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Gmail " + email;// not show gmail in html !

          console.log(info); // not show gmail here !

         }

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So can you provide the whole script and the detail flow for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to think of your issue.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, My script is get the user's gmail address when accessing the web application link. I don't know how to get the user's gmail address. I try to follow my way of thinking but can't.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this happens because your script 'doLoadGmail()' that executes the script 'checkAccSS' is only called on load. You could add a button with an onclick event that would execute your script without reloading however this wouldn't do it automaticly.

If you would like to this automaticly you could check the documentation from Ajax
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Comment: It hasn't helped me solve the problem. Can you show me more details ?