# Efficient way to search through 30k google sheet rows with javascript for mobile/desktop

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have this google sheet with 30k rows: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rzslAZJUussOGaewRYsPalM9Y_2JJbfWtJ252SlzktI/edit#gid=265140854

I'd like to create a mobile/desktop site to quickly search through the contents and  show me multiple results line by line. I'd like to search only on `column B` and on sheet `Combined`.

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this?

Comment: In my environment, I think that the methods using the Query Language and TextFinder are much faster than other methods. When you want the simple script, I recommend to use TextFinder. You can see the sample scripts at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56663168). By the way, what result do you want? From ``show me multiple results line by line.``, I couldn't understand about it.

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks I'll check it out, what I'm looking for is a solution that's works with mobile fast. I don't think loading the spreadsheet is optimal, just a simple search field then show multiple results for the query (that's what i mean line by line -- multiple rows)

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the methods using the Query Language and TextFinder, I don't measure the benchmark yet. I apologize for this. But I think that these are the best methods for searching values from Spreadsheet. Because these methods directly search the values without retrieving all values from Spreadsheet. By this, the process cost becomes lower than that of other methods.