# Is there way start a loop in a certain date range

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that is dynamically updating with leads from my marketing campaign. Currently, it has over 9K rows and will continue to grow.

I need to check values for Col F for leads that came in today; however, when I run a loop, it takes too long since it has 9k+ rows.

[image]

I want to run a loop for rows that have today's date only. Is there a way to have my script efficiently look for today's date first (without having to loop through 9k rows), and then start my loop?

Below is what I had originally. The code would start from the top of the sheet and look at Col F values and then email me if a cell had only "az-" instead of a full location value. Content below has been modified for privacy

```
function Google_Check_Lead_Values() {
var title = "Google | Leads"
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;

  var Def_url = ("website")
  ///EDIT ^ URL 

  var ss = app.openByUrl(Def_url).getSheetByName("Google | Leads");
    

var last_row = ss.getLastRow();

for (i = 1;i <=last_row; i++) {

  var location = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();

  var location_len = location.length;
if (location_len <= 3){

  MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: "email1",
          //cc: "email2",
          subject: "Discrepancy found on " + title,
          htmlBody:"Hi Team, <br>This is an automated notifcation to let you know that an issue was found on " + title + ". Please take a look at the sheet linked below: <br><br> email"
          });//end of email 
}//end of if
}//end of for

}//end of function
```

Comment: use `getValues` once instead of `getValue` in a loop

Comment: Also your code `var location = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();` returns a single value not an array so `var location_len = location.length;` will throw an error or `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of the search of value from a large sheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- In your situation, by searching the values from the columns "A" and "F", you want to send emails.

In order to search the values from a sheet, there are several methods. Using for loop, TextFinder and query language. In my test, when the query language is used, the process cost was the lowest of these 3 patterns. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to search the values using use the query language. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56663884)

#### Sample script:

```js
function Google_Check_Lead_Values() {
  var title = "Google | Leads"
  var Def_url = "###"; // Please use your Spreadsheet URL.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(Def_url);

  const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  const today = new Date();
  const tommorow = new Date();
  tommorow.setDate(tommorow.getDate() + 1);
  const vToday = Utilities.formatDate(today, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  const vTommorow = Utilities.formatDate(tommorow, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  const sheetName = "Google | Leads";
  const query = `SELECT * WHERE A >= DATE '${vToday}' AND A < date '${vTommorow}' AND E = 'az-'`;
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/gviz/tq?sheet=${sheetName}&tqx=out:csv&tq=${query}`;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(encodeURI(url), { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
  const [, ...values] = Utilities.parseCsv(res.getContentText());
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  values.forEach(_ => {
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "email1",
      //cc: "email2",
      subject: "Discrepancy found on " + title,
      htmlBody: "Hi Team, <br>This is an automated notifcation to let you know that an issue was found on " + title + ". Please take a look at the sheet linked below: <br><br> email"
    });
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the today date values are searched from the column "A", and also it searches whether the cell value of column "F" is the value of `az-`. When the values are found, the emaiil is sent. In this case, from your showing script, for example, when 2 rows are found, 2 emails are sent.
- If you know the Spreadsheet ID, you can also directly use it to `const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();` like `const spreadsheetId = "###SpreadsheetID###";`.
- In this sample script, about the search of the column "F", it seaches whether the value is `az-`. But, if you want to search the length of cell value, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const query = `SELECT * WHERE A >= DATE '${vToday}' AND A < date '${vTommorow}' AND E = 'az-'`;
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const query = `SELECT * WHERE A >= DATE '${vToday}' AND A < date '${vTommorow}' AND E MATCHES '^.{0,3}$'`;
    ```

#### References:

- [Query Language Reference (Version 0.7)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- Related thread.

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56663884

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
function Google_Check_Lead_Values() {
  const title = "Google | Leads"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url")
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(Def_url).getSheetByName(title);
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    let loc = r[5].toString();
    let d = new Date(r[0]);
    let dv = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDate()).valueOf();
    if( dv == dtv && loc.length < 4) { 
      MailApp.sendEmail({ to: "email1", subject: "Discrepancy found on " + title, htmlBody: "Hi Team, <br>This is an automated notifcation to let you know that an issue was found on " + title + ". Please take a look at the sheet linked below: <br><br> email", })
    }
  });
}
```